# How to disable the Ubuntu One file manager ribbon for specific folders?

Tags: nautilus, ubuntu-one

When I open Downloads, Pictures, Music, or Documents folders, I can see a thick beige Ubuntu One bar on top of the folder's workplace. This annoys me and, I have reasons to suppose, introduces some malfunctions. How to disable it?

I wouldn't like to totally remove Ubuntu One as I think I can make use of it in future. But for sure I am very improbable to be willing to synchronise my Downloads folder ever, as well as Videos (unless I get a gigabit Internet connection, as it contains hundreds gigabytes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click on the folder in question, and then goto `Ubuntu One > Hide Ribbon`

[image: Hide Ribbon]